# display two different currencies in two columns into a datagridview

Tags: c#

I am working on an existing piece of software and I have an object with some data members. Two of them are currencies `(double)`. I need to display them into a datagridview. I know that the right solution will be create a currency object and overload the `ToString()` method. However I cannot change (or at least it will take me a lot of re-testing) the existing object.

I have change the format value in the DefaultCellStyle and the result is almost what I want.

```
myCol.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"; display $23.56
```

I would like to customize the currency symbol as well.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I think I have found the solution:

```
myCol.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"); //display the euro symbol
```

Comment: You should put your solution in as an answer and accept it if it indeed answers your question best.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should format the value by code using a different NumberFormatInfo for the additional column, in there you can specify a different currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You solution will output something like

> 123,123.00€

If you want it looks like

> €123,123.00

you can work on the `CellFormatting` event, and put the currency symbol in front.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex) //set your columnindex accordingly..
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"), "{0:C}", d);
    }

}
```

BTW: `Decimal` is a better choice for money type object.