# C# WindowsForm add string to Bounded Data in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm using a dataGridView which got it's dataSource from a DataTable. One of the column there is named "productPrice", and the gridView column "Price" is bounded to it.
The "productPrice" data contains just the price, and I want to add to every row in this column the '$' char. How can I do it ?

-I'm not using ASP.NET so I could do Eval("productPrice")+"$", I'm using WindowsForm.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"`for the **Price** grid column.
*("c" for currency)*
[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715276/currency-format-in-datagridview-in-windows-application)

Comment: It's not working, What if I want to add something else to the column ?

Comment: @user1501674 you will have to add an event to the grid (Databound or Cell formatting,...). [Here is a similar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622535/display-two-different-currencies-in-two-columns-into-a-datagridview)